# Multiple apps / projects with one Laravel 4 installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i'm have worked with laravel 3 in the past and used a project structure where multiple apps could use one installation of the framework. now in laravel 4 i am concered if that is still possible. since the `bootstrap/autoload.php` file requires the `vendor/autoload.php` file (and so on...), different apps have to use the same autoload files from within the vendor directory, right? i think this would be a big performance problem because the different apps maybe have different requirements, different models to work with and so on. am i thinking right or is there a chance to use one `/vendor/` installation for multiple apps without the need to share the autoload files?

to explain my needs: i would like to run different apps (every app with another domain & home directory) which share one database and some models. but the requirements of every app will be very different.

is there any solution? i tried this since the release but found no practicable way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing?

You could create a route group and assign a filter function to that route group to do specific autoloads?

Comment: yes i tried, but it is not very effective if i have different root directories for every project to store cached assets (css, js) or images.

Comment: Yo marv, I know this is a year later but at the time did you consider just making different folders for each site inside of the assets folder? If you did something different could you give me an update? I'm sure whoever else comes here from Google would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

How about modifying `bootstrap/autoload.php` and `vendor/autoload.php` to load autoload stuff per project to some kind of sub-directory structure under `vendor/composer/`.

Not sure, how to change composer to generate that kind of project specific autoload directories. Maybe it needs changing composer?